# If $x \geq a$ and $y \geq b$, so is $x+y \geq a+b$?

Tags: inequality

I was doing this question related to *Trigonometry* ...

I had to prove that $\sec^2x + \csc^2x \geq 4$

So, if we prove that $\dfrac{1}{\sin^2x}+\dfrac{1}{\cos^2x} \geq 4$, our job will be done

Now, let $\dfrac {1}{\sin^2x} = a$, $\dfrac {1}{\cos^2x} = b$

$\therefore$ We just need to prove that $a+b \geq 4$

I proved that $a \geq 1$ and $b \geq 1$, which I verified using a graphing calculator app.

Now, this means that the minimum value of $a$ will be $1$ (included) and so will be the case with $b$, right?

So, wouldn't this mean that the minimum value of $a+b$ will be $1+1 = 2$ (included), so shouldn't this be correct : $a+b \geq 2$?

But this is not what we had to prove...

I think I went wrong at the part of adding both the inequalities as I verified the steps before that by graphing $y = \dfrac {1}{\sin^2x}$ and $y = \dfrac {1}{\sin^2x}$ but what I did seems pretty logical to me.

Let me know if my mistake is indeed in the addition of inequalities...

PS : My original doubt is related to what I asked and not to Trigonometry. I want to know if I the addition of inequalities that I did is faulty and if it faulty, then why is it so. Please don't solve the Trigonometry answer for me because I'd prefer to do it myself and I just added it as a reference to tell what I was solving. Thanks!!

Comment: It is true that $a+b\geq 2.$ But that would be true if $b=\frac{1}{\cos^2 y}$ for some other value $y.$ Here, you can use the relationships.

Comment: I didn't get it , can you please elaborate...

Comment: The point is. showing that $a+b\geq 2$ does not mean that you cain't show $a+b\geq 4.$ For example, can you really get $a=1$ **and** $b=1?$

Answer (score 1):

You answer is correct, but they want a better lower bound.With some trigonometry, it gets obvious:
$$\frac{1}{\sin^2x}+\frac{1}{\cos^2x}=\frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{(\sin x\cos x)^2}=\frac1{\Bigl(\frac12\sin2x\Bigr)^{\!2}}=\frac 4{\sin^22x}\ge 4$$
since $\:0<\sin^22x \le 1$.

Comment: You use : $sin(x)cos(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}sin(2x)$ here. I haven't learned that yet.

Comment: Didn't you learn the addition formulæ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it, my answer is correct and wrong, how??

Comment: Is something is at least 4, it is *a fortiori* at  least 2. He who can do the more can do the less. I meant that your answer is true, but it is not what they asked to prove.

Comment: Nope, all I learned is representation of Trigonometric ratios on a unit circle, proving trigonometric identities using the knowledge of the unit circle and finding trigonometric ratios of some standard angles using it, along with some standard formula like : $cos(2n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}=0$, when $n \in \Bbb Z$ and that $sin(n\pi)=0$, when $n \in \Bbb Z$, nothing else!

Comment: oh, I get it now...

Comment: Ìf you don't know at least $\cos(a+b)=\cdots$ and $\sin(a+b)=\cdots$, I don't see how you could prove it.